# Capturing User Authentication Cookies in Flutter Desktop App from a Website: Seeking Guidance

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and currently working on a third-party linux desktop app that needs to capture user authentication from a website's login page. Here's the scenario:

- The website employs a combination of user credentials and session management for authentication and user session maintenance.
- I'm looking for guidance on how to capture session cookies in Flutter so that I can perform backend requests.
- While I've reviewed [GitHub's OAuth2 app codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-github-client#3) flow using the `url_launcher` package, the website I'm dealing with doesn't use OAuth2.

I'm considering using headless browser automation tools like Puppeteer, Playwright, or WebDriver to interact with the login page programmatically.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this challenge effectively. Thanks in advance!